# ActiveMQ Artemis publish message loss during HA fail-over

Tags: activemq-artemis

I use ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0, and I'm looking to avoid message loss in a producer during fail-over.

Message publish loss handled during Artemis active to passive switch by catching `ActiveMQUnBlockedException` and sending the message again.
The brokers are configured as active/passive HA shared-store. Active node configured in `host1` and passive node configured in `host2`.
Url is:

```
(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?ha=true&reconnectAttempts=-1&blockOnDurableSend=false
```

`blockOnDurableSend` set to `false` for high throughput.
During active to passive switch publishing code throws `ActiveMQUnBlockedException` but not during passive to active switching.

We're using Spring 4.2.5 and `CachingConnectionFactory` for connection factory.

I'm using the following code to send messages:

```java
private void sendMessageInternal(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, final Destination queue, final String message)
        throws JMSException {

    try (final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();) {
        connection.start();
        try (final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);) {
            final TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
            producer.send(textMessage);
        }

    } catch (JMSException thr) {
        if (thr.getCause() instanceof ActiveMQUnBlockedException) {
            // consider as fail-over disconnection, send message again.
        } else {
            throw thr;
        }
    }
}
```

In host1 machine, Artemis deployed as master - node1.
In host2 machine, Artemis deployed as slave - node2.
following steps I did to simulate fail-over

1. node1 and node2 started
2. node1 started as live server and node2 started as backup server
3. killed node1, node2 become live server
4. client publish code threw `ActiveMQUnBlockedException` and handled to send message again
5. started node1 again. node1 become live server and node2 become backup again
6. client publish code did not throw `ActiveMQUnBlockedException` and loss in message.

Getting following error stack during step #3. ( Killed node1 and node2 become Live server).

```
javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ219016: Connection failure detected. Unblocking a blocking call that will never get a response
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:540)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:434)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sessionStop(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:470)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.stop(ClientSessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.stop(ClientSessionImpl.java:1110)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.stop(ActiveMQSession.java:1244)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection.stop(ActiveMQConnection.java:339)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.localStop(SingleConnectionFactory.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:577)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.eu.amq.failover.test.ProducerNodeTest.sendMessageInternal(ProducerNodeTest.java:133)
    at com.eu.amq.failover.test.ProducerNodeTest.sendMessage(ProducerNodeTest.java:110)
    at com.eu.amq.failover.test.ProducerNodeTest.main(ProducerNodeTest.java:90)
```

Comment: What I meant by "passive to active switching" is when I kill active Artemis server, passive Artemis server will become active, simulating a fail-over scenario.

Comment: Edited the post to add message publish code. `ActiveMQUnBlockedException` throws correctly during active to passive failover, but not during on reverse switch.

Comment: Edited the post to add  the steps how I simulated fail-over.

Comment: Edited the post to add exception details. Since I start the connection before the operation,   close/stop invoke sendBlocking even though I set `blockOnDurableSend=false`.

Comment: Now I tried with `blockOnDurableSend=true` and without `connection.start()`, getting `ActiveMQUnBlockedException' during both cases( step #3 and #5 ). I am able to avoid message loss. Setting 'blockOnDurableSend=true' is the only way to avoid message loss during Artemis fail-over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ActiveMQUnBlockedException` you're getting is coming from Spring's invocation of `javax.jms.Connection#stop`. It's not related to sending a message. Re-sending a message when you get this specific exception could result in a duplicate message.

Ultimately your problem is directly related to setting `blockOnDurableSend=false`. This tells the client to "fire and forget." In other words the client won't wait for a response from the broker to ensure the message actually made it successfully. This lack of waiting increases throughput but *decreases* reliability.

If you really want to mitigate potential message loss you have two main options.

Set `blockOnDurableSend=true`. This will reduce message throughput, but it's the simplest way to guarantee the message arrived at the broker successfully.

Use a [`CompletionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/CompletionListener.html). This will allow you to keep `blockOnDurableSend=false`, but the application will still be informed if there are problems sending the message although the information will be provided asynchronously. This feature was added in JMS 2 specifically for this kind of scenario. See the JavaDoc for more details.